# Apply a filter on FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to display chat messages.

```
private void attachRecyclerViewAdapter() {
    lastFifty = mChatRef.limitToLast(50).;
    mRecyclerViewAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(
            Chat.class, R.layout.message, ChatHolder.class, lastFifty) {

        @Override
        public void populateViewHolder(ChatHolder chatView, Chat chat, int position) {
            chatView.setName(chat.getName());
            chatView.setText(chat.getText());
            chatView.setTimeLocation(chat.getTime());
            FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (currentUser != null && chat.getUid().equals(currentUser.getUid())) {
                chatView.setIsSender(true);
            } else {
                chatView.setIsSender(false);
            }
        }
    };
```

I have a list that contains list of specific users. I would like to apply filter to see only messages from those specific users. What should I do ?

Comment: There is an open [feature request on FirebaseUI for adding the ability to filter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/15).

Comment: It would always be best practice to try and do the filtering on the server side. Have you looked into stopping users from sending messages to other users which they have not yet added or have blocked? In an app I am working on I allow users to add any user they want but I only allow them to send messages if the other user has also added them.

Comment: -1
down vote
 

have you considered using a dedicated node on the Firebase Database for those specific users?

Comment: are you tryin to implemet a group chat?

Answer (score 2):

You can create messages with user id pair nodes. For example ***messages->'uid1-uid2'->...***

To prevent which is first order uids alphatecially as the following messageId generator code does:

```
public static String getMessageId(String id1, String id2){
        String messageId;

        if(id1.compareTo(id2) < 0){
            messageId = id1 + "-" + id2;
        }else if(id1.compareTo(id2) > 0) {
            messageId = id2 + "-" + id1;
        }else{
            messageId = id1;
        }

        return messageId;
    }
```

When you want to see the chat history between a user and urself, obtain the user's id and generate `messageId = getMessageId(id1, id2); or  messageId = getMessageId(id2, id1);` gives the same result since the order doesn't affect the result.

Then call the messages from the node ***messages -> messageId***

**P.S.** you should restructure your messages node as i describe.

**EDIT**

You can convert messageId to md5 equivalent to save chars.

just change

```
return messageId;
```

to

```
return md5(messageId);
```

where md5 is:

```
public static String md5(final String s) {
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest
                .getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(s.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```